sticky not working for sidenav in nextjs 14
i am trying to make the sidenav sticky but its not working
"use client"
import { useState } from "react";
import AnalyticsSideNav from "./_components/AnalyticsSideNav";
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
import "./styles/layout.css";
const AnalyticsRootLayout = ({ children }) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const pathname = usePathname();
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col h-auto md:flex-row flex-1 min-h-[88vh] max-h-auto noscroll">
            {pathname === "/login" || pathname === "/Unauthorized" ? "" : (
                <aside
                    className={`bg-white-100  flex pt-[8%]  w-full h-auto overflow-auto noscroll ${!open ? "overflow-hidden md:w-[70px]" : "md:w-48 overflow-hidden"
                        }  transition-width duration-500 ease-in-out sticky top-0 `}
                >
                <AnalyticsSideNav open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
                </aside>
            )}
            <main className="flex-1 h-auto overflow-y-auto noscroll pl-3 pr-3">{children}</main>
        </div>
    );
};
export default AnalyticsRootLayout;

even i tried to add external css and !important still its not working ,
also i dont want to set the height of sidenav manually , it should be auto in my case
here is the dummy setup i made here

Are you sure your tailwind is working? I can't see it's working in the dummy setup shared by you.

If I add custom styling to aside element it's working. Try to add this to aside element
style={{ position: 'sticky', top: 0 }}
